# Pesquisar no banco quando carregar a página

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Quando carregar a página quero que faça uma consulta no banco e verificar que o resultado trouxe mais de 3 resultados, se trouxer quero que bloqueia um checkbox. 
Como posso fazer isso? Estou usando JQuery, PHP, MySQL.

Comment: `$('[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled', true)`, quando obtiver o retorno: `$('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('disabled')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de várias maneiras, vai depender de como é sua página. Por exemplo, você pode simplesmente fazer a consulta no início da página antes de renderizar qualquer HTML e verificar a condição, se for verdadeira na hora de adicionar o checkbox você coloca o atributo *disabled*.

Outra forma, seria fazer um ajax que retorna a quantidade de registros ou mesmo um valor booleano e bloquear o input a depender do resultado.

Usando ajax:

```
$.get('consulta.php', function(registros) {
  if (registros > 3) {
    $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Usando PHP direto no início da página:

```
//não sei como você está acessado o banco ... 
$iQtdRegistros = query();
$attr = $iQtdRegistros > 3 ? "disabled='disabled'" : '';


<input type="checkbok" <?php echo $attr; ?> >
```

Comment: Valeu Jorge, ficou bem melhor o texto.